# Migration from ansible 2.7 to 2.12 problem with cisco.ios.ios_command module

Tags: automation, ansible, ansible-2.x

Hello i ave a problem since my migration to ansible 2.7 to 2.12.

I use my old playbook with cisco.ios.ios_command and i have this error when i try to send my ios command:

`fatal: [192.168.1.12]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "ssh connection failed: ssh connect failed: kex error : no match for method kex algos: server [diffie-hellman-group1-sha1], client [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1]"}`

This is my ansible config :

`ansible [core 2.12.2] config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules'] ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible ansible collection location = /root/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections executable location = /usr/bin/ansible python version = 3.8.13 (default, Jun 14 2022, 17:49:07) [GCC 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-13)] jinja version = 2.11.3 libyaml = True`

This is my ansible.cfg :

```
[defaults]

host_key_checking = False
ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1
callback_whitelist = profile_tasks
log_path = /var/log/ansible_portugal.log

[persistent_connection]

connect_timeout = 240
command_timeout = 60
#ssh_type = libssh

[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ServerAliveInterval=30
```

And my code is :

```
- name: task name
  hosts: ALL
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  roles:
     - role-cisco


role-cisco:

    - name: "Verification de la configuration -- SSH --"
      retries: 2
      delay: 5
      cisco.ios.ios_command:
        # running_config: none
        commands:
          - show run
      vars:
        ansible_connection: network_cli
        ansible_network_os: cisco.ios.ios
        ansible_user: "{{ username_ansible }}"
        ansible_password: "{{ password_ansible }}"
```

i tried to add "ansible_ssh_common_args: "-o KexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1" to my task vars but it didn't work ...

I thing I must add some things in collection per exemple but I don't know what because i think ansible 2.12 does'nt work like 2.7

Tks for you help :)

I tried to add "ansible_ssh_common_args: "-o KexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1" to my task vars but it didn't work ...

I expecting :

succes task :

`ok: [192.168.1.12]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem:

I must to add this parameter in my playbook :

```
  vars:
    ansible_network_cli_ssh_type: paramiko
```

After that, I can use my playbook as I want.